# WSO2 APIM 4.2.0 issue with accessing rest api endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Requested URL path via publisher api is `https://localhost:8243/myorders/v0/api/v1/myorders/category` which gives `404` error response
whereas the Rest endpoint which is working correctly via swagger/postman is `http://localhost:8097/api/v1/myorders/category`

What shall I do to enable the publisher portal to correct the requested url path.

CORS is enabled and context is set to `/myorders` and version is `v0` is Publisher portal

Endpoint configured is `http://localhost:8097/` where my springboot application is running.

Any help would be appreciated.

Besides this on startup my WSO2 gives the following errors though I am able to access the publisher portal and add my API's I am unable to test them

```
[2023-07-14 16:08:32,876] ERROR - JMXServerManager Could not create the RMI local registry
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9999; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

[2023-07-14 16:08:38,011] ERROR - JMXServerManager Could not initialize RMI server
java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(RMIConnectorServer.java:834) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointException: Error while opening socket to 10.254.87.185:9711. Permission denied: connect
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.java:75) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.3.5.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.3.5.jar:?]
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212) ~[commons-pool_1.5.6.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:137) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.3.5.jar:?]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

Resolved port error by killing bg process, the following error persists -

Killed background application running on the same port, JMX error resolved, Thanks however still facing the below error while starting the WSO2 APIM -

```
ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:147) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.3.5.jar:?]
atorg.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.3.5.jar:?]
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[?:?]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
 at Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointException: Error while opening socket to 10.254.87.185:9711. Permission denied: connect
```

Thanks,

Comment: As per the error message you shared, it seems another instance of WSO2 API Manager is running in your environment and is blocking the connections to port: 9999. Furthermore, this can be due to also some other applications that are using the 9999 port running in your environment. Regarding the 404 behaviour, please check whether the mentioned API is published and deployed properly in your environment

Comment: Killed background application running on the same port, JMX error resolved, Thanks however still facing the below error while starting the WSO2 APIM - ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://10.254.87.185:9711

Comment: What is the base OS image that you are using? Is it Linux (Ubuntu or any) or Windows? Seems like the latest error is that the API Manager doesn't have permission to open the Socket. Also, mention the Java version

Comment: @Athiththan
I am trying to do an installation on Windows 11,  JDK 17 is being used

Comment: Please check whether you have any Firewall configurations blocking to open o any respective Ports for the WSO2 API Manager in your environment.

Comment: The error won't go and I could not rewire org policies to disable firewalls, hence resorted to installing wso2apim via docker container looking at steps mentioned in the official docs.